# Avoid SPNEGO authentication for each request

Tags: java, security, webserver, jetty, spnego

I have a webserver which is using Jetty underneath along with SPNEGO authenticator and login service. I am using Firefox to connect to this webserver and can see that authentication is happening properly. But the issue is for each request from web client authentication is happening again and again, rather than only at first request. Does Jetty store any information to differentiate between an authenticated and unauthenticated user ? If not then can someone please help to recommend how I can achieve that? Also what it means to logout a user already authenticated using SPNEGO ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not SPNEGO authentication but how you are managing session.

Once authenticated create a HTTP session and add the user's details to the session, and using a Filter check that there is a valid session is present if not do the authentication else skip the authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also I see in ServletContextHandler there is only 1 security handler which can be set. Is there a way to set multiple security handlers ?  I was thinking if I can create a WrapperSecurityHandler and compose 2 security handlers inside it. Then based on request type use the specific security handler inside WrapperSecurityHandler to do the authentication. Then I can just set this WrapperSecurityHandler as security handler of ServletContextHandler. But am facing issues in this approach so was wondering if there is any other way or it's a limitation in Jetty.